# Why might these options price so far from the square-root of duration?

Tags: option-pricing

In general, to first order, option prices rise with the square root of duration (i.e., time-to-expiration).

I was just looking at puts on U.S. ETF `FXI` and they grossly violate this rule.  With `FXI` trading at 39, the current ask on **strike 35 puts** (i.e., ~10% OTM) is as follows:

```
Days to Exp     Ask     Implied Vol     Sqrt(Duration)  $/Day
22  $0.07  29%             4.7             $0.015 
50  $0.22  27%             7.1             $0.031 
78  $0.35  25%             8.8             $0.040 
113   $0.70  24%             10.6            $0.066
```

This makes no sense: Even though the implied vol on the longer duration options is lower, the price per day increases vastly faster than $\sqrt{Duration}$.  (In fact, it is roughly $Duration^{1.5}$!)  What am I missing?

Comment: What are the strikes of these options?

Comment: @will: 35 (presently 10% OTM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "square-root rule" for time-to-expiration only (roughly) applies when the spot price = strike price.  Even in that case there is a second-order term that is a function of the risk-free rate and implied volatility.

This can be seen in the [Black-Scholes pricing formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model#Black%E2%80%93Scholes_formula): the time-to-expiration is included in a term that also varies with log(spot/strike), and that is then transformed by the normal distribution:

$$\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{T - t}}\left[\ln\left(\frac{S_t}{K}\right) + \left(r + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)(T - t)\right]$$

where *S* is spot, *K* is strike, (*T - t*) is time-to-expiration.

So there's no easy rule or equation for option price as a function of time-to-expiration!

Comment: Should it be forward = strike rather than spot = strike?

Comment: @CharlesFox: In this case I don't believe so because the underlying is a stock, so the only difference between the "spot" and any "forward" prices should be accounted in the risk-free rate, which is included in this formulation of Black-Scholes.